# regex: How to match a directory (but not a 'normal' file)?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex which matches directories but not standard files (in the current working directory).

Looking for the '.' contained in a file extension is obviously too simple, there can be folders containing dots.

Comment: What operating system?  How is the list of the local directory being generated?

Comment: You have to ask yourself what's different about filenames versus directory names. There is no inherent difference, so you can't do this with regex.

Comment: I don't see any regex that can do such thing.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04. The 'motivation' comes from a different direction: I would like to check (from Emacs) whether the point (cursor) is on a directory or not.

Comment: Actually, how would one match 'everything not containing a dot'? That would at least be a good 'heuristic' in the application I have in mind.

Comment: A regex has absolutely no concept of what a file or directory is. At best, a regex deals with a byte string (or possibly a Unicode code point sequence, or other type of sequence) that may or may not have any concrete semantic meaning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in comments:

> Actually, how would one match 'everything not containing a dot'?

You could do : `^[^.]+$`

Comment: what if folder name is "hahaha.hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming you are refering to the Windows OS:
Using regex to determine that would not be the right way. Because a file can have no extension and a folder can have a period and an extension as part of its name.
The best approach is to use FileAttributes in the code like this (.NET C#):

```
// get the file attributes for file or directory
FileAttributes attributeUnknown = File.GetAttributes(@"C:\MariusHofert");

//detect whether its a directory or file
if((attributeUnknown & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
    MessageBox.Show("Its a directory");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Its a file");
```

[Reference Link](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/248663-how-tell-if-path-file-directory)

Comment: As per OP it is `Ubuntu 13.04`

Comment: Yeah he put that in his comments later.